# Need help in optimising query

Tags: php, mysql, join, phpmyadmin, performance

I have two tables - `incoming tours(id,name)` and `incoming_tours_cities(id_parrent, id_city)`

`id` in first table is unique, and for each unique row from first table there is the list of `id_city` - s in second table(i.e. `id_parrent` in second table is equal to `id` from first table)

For example

`incoming_tours`

```
|--id--|------name-----|
|---1--|---first_tour--|
|---2--|--second_tour--|
|---3--|--thirth_tour--|
|---4--|--hourth_tour--|
```

`incoming_tours_cities`

```
|-id_parrent-|-id_city-|
|------1-----|---4-----|
|------1-----|---5-----|
|------1-----|---27----|
|------1-----|---74----|
|------2-----|---1-----|
|------2-----|---5-----|
........................
```

That means that `first_tour` has list of cities - `("4","5","27","74")`

AND `second_tour` has list of cities - `("1","5")`

---

Let's assume i have two values - `4` and `74`:

Now, i need to get all rows from first table, where my **both** values are in the list of cities. i.e it must return only the **first_tour** (because 4 and 74 are in it's list of cities)

So, i wrote the following query

```
SELECT t.name
FROM `incoming_tours` t
JOIN `incoming_tours_cities` tc0 ON tc0.id_parrent = t.id
AND tc0.id_city = '4'
JOIN `incoming_tours_cities` tc1 ON tc1.id_parrent = t.id
AND tc1.id_city = '74'
```

And that works fine.

But i generate the query dynamically, and when the count of joins is big (about 15) the query slowing down.

i.e. when i try to run

```
SELECT t.name
FROM `incoming_tours` t
JOIN `incoming_tours_cities` tc0 ON tc0.id_parrent = t.id
AND tc0.id_city = '4'
JOIN `incoming_tours_cities` tc1 ON tc1.id_parrent = t.id
AND tc1.id_city = '74'
.........................................................
JOIN `incoming_tours_cities` tc15 ON tc15.id_parrent = t.id
AND tc15.id_city = 'some_value'
```

the query run's in `45s`(despite on i set indexes in the tables)

What can i do, to optimaze it?

Thanks much

Comment: you do join with the same table 14 times ?

Comment: YES, because i have to check for 14 values.

Comment: if there is another way to reach same effect, please tell me how

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT t.name
FROM incoming_tours t INNER JOIN 
  ( SELECT id_parrent
    FROM incoming_tours_cities
    WHERE id IN (4, 74)
    GROUP BY id_parrent
    HAVING count(id_city) = 2) resultset 
  ON resultset.id_parrent = t.id
```

But you need to change number of total cities count.

Comment: You take only the parent_ids that have matched your list of cities twice. That way you know that they have both cities.

Comment: Oh, and replace `id` with `id_city`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name
FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT(incoming_tours.name) AS name,
             COUNT(incoming_tours_cities.id_city) AS c
      FROM incoming_tours
           JOIN incoming_tours_cities
                ON incoming_tours.id=incoming_tours_cities.id_parrent
      WHERE incoming_tours_cities.id_city IN(4,74)
            HAVING c=2
      ) t1;
```

You will have to change `c=2` to whatever the count of `id_city` you are searching is, but since you generate the query dynamically, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Doesn't seem like it - I've tested it and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this works, but a lot less sure that it is optimal.

```
SELECT * FROM incoming_tours 
WHERE 
id IN (SELECT id_parrent FROM incoming_tours_cities WHERE id_city=4)
AND id IN (SELECT id_parrent FROM incoming_tours_cities WHERE id_city=74)
...
AND id IN (SELECT id_parrent FROM incoming_tours_cities WHERE id_city=some_value)
```

Comment: I've now had a look at the query execution times, too. It doesn't seem to be a lot slower at lower values of conditions, but it does seem to be much quicker to have many `SELECT` subqueries than to have the same number of `JOIN` conditions for higher numbers of conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Just an hint.
If you use the `IN` operator in a `WHERE` clause, you can hope that the short-circuit of operator `AND` may remove unnecessary `JOIN`s during the execution for the tours that do not respect the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an odd way to do that query, here

```
SELECT t.name FROM `incoming_tours` as t WHERE t.id IN (SELECT id_parrent FROM `incoming_tours_cities` as tc WHERE tc.id_city IN ('4','74'));
```

I *think* that does it, but not tested...

*EDIT: Added table alias to sub-query*

Comment: this will not work, because i need **all** values to match, but when you wrote `in` it is equal to `or`, not `and` statement verification.

Comment: i.e. after runing your query with values of (`"5"`,`"74"`) you will get both `first_tour` and `second_tour`, but we need the first only.

Comment: I ran my query after re-creating the tables from the example, and it returns first_tour only.

Comment: Try it with values "4" and "5" (where 5 is in the second_tour as well as the first) and then you will see that this query will not work

Comment: Yeah, noticed that after I posted my comment

Answer (score 0):

I've written this query using CTE's and it includes the test data in the query. You'll need to modify it so that it queries the real tables instead. Not sure how it performs on a large dataset...

```
Declare @numCities int = 2

;with incoming_tours(id, name) AS
(
    select 1, 'first_tour' union all
    select 2, 'second_tour' union all
    select 3, 'third_tour' union all
    select 4, 'fourth_tour' 
)
, incoming_tours_cities(id_parent, id_city) AS
(
    select 1, 4 union all 
    select 1, 5 union all 
    select 1, 27 union all 
    select 1, 74 union all 
    select 2, 1 union all 
    select 2, 5
)
, cityIds(id_city) AS
( 
    select 4
    union all select 5
    /* Add all city ids you need to check in this table */
)
, common_cities(id_city, tour_id, tour_name) AS
(
    select c.id_city,  it.id, it.name
    from cityIds C, Incoming_tours_cities tc, incoming_tours it
    where C.id_city = tc.id_city
    and tc.id_parent = it.id
)
, tours_with_all_cities(id_city) As
(
    select tour_id from common_cities 
    group by tour_id 
    having COUNT(id_city) = @numCities
)
select it.name from incoming_tours it, tours_with_all_cities tic
where it.id = tic.id_city
```